# Can a 9 V battery kill you?

Tags: energy, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

Suppose I connect a 9 V DC battery to a DC-to-AC converter. Then connect the output of the converter to a step-up transformer, which increases the voltage to 2000 V. Now, if I put myself between the ends of the terminals of the secondary circuit of the transformer (i.e. I'm the load), will I be electrocuted? (Assuming my body resistance to be 1000 Ohms.)

I think 2000 V and 1000 Ohms can produce about 2 A of current through my body, which could be fatal. This means I'm drawing about 4000 J of energy per second from the battery. A quick google search tells me that a standard 9 V battery may contain 20,000 J of energy. If that's true, 2 A current will go through my body for about 5 seconds before the battery is completely drained. I'll be fried like a potato for sure if that happens.

Are my reasoning and numbers fairly correct? Can a 9 V battery kill you?

Also, what would happen if the 9 V DC is coming from an adapter connected to a 230 V AC power source and not from a DC battery? If I'm the load, would 2 A current flow non-stop through my body in such a scenario (until the AC power source is depleted)?

Comment: A standard 9 V battery is comprised of 6 series AAAA batteries, more or less: you can carefully take a dead one apart with pliers and see for yourself. These cells are smaller than AAA cells, so this post might help: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/591473/223146. In college, I once built a tickler circuit that stepped up the output of a 9 V battery to around 1200 V. I was going to use it for a prank, but got zapped right after I finished construction. Decided to skip the prank. No real harm, but not funny in any event. Ps. I did not down vote.

Comment: I do not know what batteries or circuitry is used in stun guns, but maybe someone here can comment on that, if relevant.

Comment: @Ed V Okay, so is my math on energy and stuff approximately correct?

Comment: The 9 volt battery probably can't deliver enough power to kill you, but if you charged a capacitor and used that, you would be in real danger.

Comment: Even dead shorted, you cannot get 2 amps from a 9 V battery for very long, so I don’t think your numbers are realistic. Basically, the battery will overheat and polarize (be rate limited at the electrodes). It is basically the power issue, as @DavidWhite commented.

Comment: Your estimate for human resistance is quite low, on average the resistance of a (dry) human is more like $1 \text{ M}\Omega$ if the leads are directly attached to your outer skin layers.

Answer (score 3):

If you had 2A at 2000V, it would be  a minimum of 444 A for the batterie, so the voltage will drop to almost zero since the inner resistance of a 9V batterie is about 0.5 Ohm.

Comment: The cells are connected in series, so it is still 2 A per cell.

Comment: In the question it was a transformer which made the 2000V not some 220 cells in series, an for  ideal transformers I*U=const .  so  2000V*2A =9V*444.4..A, so if this is the reason of down voting , please correct it.

Comment: Transformer is actually too complicated a device; any inductor massive enough that would keep the 100mA+ current for some milliseconds after disconnecting the battery by bare hands could kill a human. And I just measured the secondary of a MOT to be some 100 Ω. Do not try at home.